# Geometry problem involves median of a triangle and a point on the median

Tags: geometry

This is not homework.

In triangle ABC,$C_1$ is the midpoint of AB. P is a point on $CC_1$. AP intersect BC at $A_1$ and BP intersect AC at $B_1$. Prove that $A_1B_1$ is parallel to AB.

My attempt:
Extend $CC_1$ to C' so $CC_1$=$C_1C'$. Now ABC and ABC' are symmetrical. P' is on CC' and $PC_1$=$P'C_1$. Construct $A_1'$ and $B_1'$ similarly. ABPP' and CBC'A are both parallelograms. What should I do now?

Sorry I don't know how to put a diagram on.

**EDIT:This is the diagram:**[image]

Comment: assume A_1B_1 and AB are not parallel get a contradiction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Ceva's Theorem,
$$\frac{AC_1}{C_1B}\cdot\frac{BA_1}{A_1C}\cdot\frac{CB_1}{B_1A}=1$$

As $AC_1=C_1B$,

$$\frac{BA_1}{A_1C}=\frac{B_1A}{CB_1}$$

So, we have

$$\frac{BC}{A_1C}=\frac{AC}{B_1C}$$

$\triangle ABC\sim \triangle B_1A_1C$ and hence $A_1B_1\parallel BA$.